# How do I use に and を with 繋ぎ留める?

Tags: grammar, translation

I've been reading web novels and found the word "繋ぎ止める"here. https://syosetu.org/novel/47581/34.html. I'm not really sure how に and を can be used here?

> 君に私を繋ぎ留められてる

Does this mean "I'm being bound/restricted by you" "I'm being bound/restricted to you"? or "I'm restricting you."?

Comment: The linked page only has 彼のおかげで繋ぎ留められてる. Is 君に私を繋ぎ留められてる your own sentence?

Comment: Yeah. I'm always confused when "君に私を" is used so I want to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems [to be 止, not 留](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E7%B9%8B%E3%81%8E%E6%AD%A2%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B). And you probably mean "私は君に繋ぎ止められてる".

I am not familiar with this verb but I think it has a positive meaning without nuance of restriction.
Based on what I found it would either mean 1) fasten something so it stays put (like a boat), or 2) make it so that a relationship hols on, doesn't fall apart.

In your text, I would see it like "I'm getting weak but thanks to him, things(?) are still holding."

Comment: I see. So does "君に私を繋ぎ止められてる" mean something like "I'm keeping you from falling apart." or "You're keeping me from falling apart"?

Comment: I don't think your sentence is proper japanese so can't say.